# Custom markup for the comment form

Tags: comment-form

**The issue**

The comment form, as i planned to design it, will use Bootstrap's input groups and probably input addons. Translating in bare coins, the needed markup for each input is like this:

```
<section class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your name" />
</section>
```

Wordpress function `comment_form()`, as far as i know, doesn't allow this kind of markup. I can give id or classes to the `form`, to the `submit` button, but i was not able to find anything that lets me add wrapping elements and classes to inputs.

**The question**

Since i don't want to write my own function, cause i'm concerned about plugins not being able to function properly, is there a way to do this using as much native functions as possible? Thank you.

**EDIT**

To avoid any misunderstanding, if not clear, i'm not asking a question about Bootstrap itself, but just how should i generate a precise markup with Wordpress.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333810/how-to-customize-wordpress-comment-form

Comment: @WebElaine And that won't cause issues? After all it is writing a custom function instead of using wp's one

Comment: Most sites are customized at least a little, whether it's custom functions or filters. Shouldn't cause issues unless you let the site sit there for 5 years without updating your code to later standards. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this should be possible using the [comment_form_default_field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)s filter, like so:

`apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields );`

```
$fields = array( 'name' => '<section class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your name" />
</section>'
);
```

Just remember to add any other fields that you want to add into that array too.

Comment: Ok going to try that

Comment: Very well, it's working.